# Why was "SSD read/write usage & AntiVirus impact on SSD life" closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

I made a question regarding SSDs and Antivirus here:

https://superuser.com/questions/379790/ssd-read-write-usage-antivirus-impact-on-ssd-life

Three users closed this question claiming that it was answered via this question:
[Antivirus impact on SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/218245/antivirus-impact-on-ssd)

However, there were very few responses in that question and only two answers, neither of which were accepted.  I fear that the community members who closed my question did not fully read the question they were referring to, as I asked a more specific version of that original question and the answers provided in the referred to topic I felt were not sufficient (they simply said 'you should be OK' and "Antivirus will have very little impact on your SSD' with nothing to back up their answers)

Could I get my question reopened?  I really do need advice on my current SSD situation.

Comment: Current readers of your question can go to the duplicate to post their answers. Leave a comment explaining on your question that the answers on the duplicate are insufficient. If your question is truly not a duplicate, then you need to *focus it more and help readers understand what your question is specifically.*

Comment: If you read my question, you'll see that I've taken several efforts on my part to prevent the degradation of my SSD and that I've taken an effort to make the question more focused - I specified that I'm concerned about the additional read/writes AVs have to their tendency to write to logs on the system (SSD) drive.  I also requested a clarification on whether a 1 GB file write would have more or less wear and tear on my SSD vs several 1k file writes.

The related question does not have the same type of focus as mines, nor do the answers in the related question.

Comment: I read your question again, and I still don't know what you are asking.  SuperUser is not a discussion forum; it is a Q&A site.  You need to ask a question that can be answered, not merely discussed.

Comment: Anyway, anti-virus programs mostly do reads, not writes, as the answers in the original question attest.

Comment: The question was not meant to be a discussion question.  I was asking if Antivirus software cause additional reads/writes (and therefore shorten SSD life) due to their constant writes to log files on the system drive and why or why not.  I was not asking for what Antivirus software to use to minimize this, I simply wanted to know if the constant changes to log files can shorten an SSD's life.  I will make a new post with a more focused version of the question - my intent was not for it to be a discussion, but rather a "yes and here's why" or a "no and here's why" answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you delete the old post first.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Maybe wait more than 30 minutes to get an answer on Meta. It takes a day or so sometimes. Think of time zones, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You're basically asking the same question again. If you aren't happy with the question, you can throw in a bounty on the original question to get the exposure that you want.

Comment: @White Phoenix A bounty could have a bit of added text in it also, like indicating that logging writes were important to you the bounty placer, even if it was not discussed in the original answers. I think this sucks because in this situation the answers there were weak and left out some things (not that anyone would expect that all AVPs would be tested to know everything asked).  But that is what the bounty could do, get improvments, and more views.